# Where does Homestead/Vagrant put folders?

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm new to app development, new to Laravel and new to Homestead. I've just successfully served up my first 'hello world' home page via Vagrant/Homestead.

I have a few of questions:

1. Assuming my config is the following:

   ```
   folders:
       - map: ~/Documents/projects/tests
         to: /home/vagrant/tests

   sites:
       - map: test1.local
         to: /home/vagrant/tests/laravel1/HTML/public
   ```

   Where the is the `/home/vagrant/tests` folder physically located? Or, where can I find this kind of info (apart from here)?
2. I started the server with `vagrant up`. Ok. I see no logs on the Terminal. I was used to have logs during requests. So will the server run forever and ever? Or how to eventually shut it down?
3. How to see logs?

Comment: You already have the answer in your question. You local directory is the value set to `map` and the value set to `to` is the directory in the VM. If you read it correctly : Map x to y.

Comment: Not what I asked. I know where my files are, but where the is the /home/vagrant/tests folder physically located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where the hell is `/home/vagrant/tests folder` physically located? Or, where can I find this kind of info (apart from here)?

The `/home/vagrant` folder is stored in the virtual hard disk of the virtual machine. You cannot access it from your host OS.

On *my* computer, it's located in `~/.vagrant.d/boxes/laravel-VAGRANTSLASH-homestead/5.1.0/virtualbox/ubuntu-16.04-amd64-disk001.vmdk`. It may differ on your machine.

It doesn't matter where that directory is though, because the real files are stored in the `~/Documents/Projects/tests` directory which is mapped to the virtual hard disk. Any changes that you need to make to these files, you should be making in that directory.

> I started the server with `vagrant up`. Ok. I see no logs on the Terminal. I was used to have logs during requests. So will the server run forever and ever? Or how to eventually shut it down?

The machine will run until it's stopped, using `vagrant halt` or you shut down your machine.

> How to see logs?

Laravel stores your logs in `storage/logs` within the Laravel directory. Based on your configuration, you should have log files in the `~/Documents/projects/tests/Laravel1/HTML/storage/logs` directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. It’s on your VM, so it’s inside the VM’s directroy. Depending on what VM you’re using, it’ll be in there.
2. The oposite of `vagrant up` is `vagrant halt`

Comment: My current VM is VirtualBox. Still, I cannot locate the physical place where the /home/vagrant/ folder is. If I open up VirtualBOx and see the virtual machine, I can right click it and choose view in finder. It will take me to /myuser/Virtual Box VMs/myvirtualbox. Fine. But there is no /home/vagrant folder there. There's a myvirtualbox.vbox, but i cannot open it.

Comment: Unfortunatly that’s not how VMs work, the files inside it are stored on its own drive – you can’t access them to the same way. Which is why Vagrant uses mapping.

Answer (score 1):

1. As mapped so in `~/Documents/projects/tests` on host OS and `~/tests/laravel1/HTML` in guest OS
2. `vagrant halt` (from same directory where you issued `vagrant up`)
3. Logs on Ubuntu are in `/var/log/apache2/access.log` and `/var/log/apache2/error.log` by default. Application (PHP error within) you can see in (in your case) `/home/vagrant/tests/laravel1/HTML/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Not asked how but

4. You access your guest server virtual machine with `vagrant ssh` command